# Neo4j Help to sort comments list with CYPHER

Tags: neo4j, neo4j.rb

My application has an object "comments" where users can rate each comment as "positive" and "negative", I want to sort my comments based on a count (number of positive - amount of negative) based on that score I want to sort comments through a cypher query.

Does anyone know help me get this query?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Vagueness is the anathema of questions.

Comment: Show your data model.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a wild guess:

```
MATCH (cid:Comment)
RETURN (cid.plus_rating_count - cid.negative_rating_count) 
ORDER BY (cid.plus_rating_count - cid.negative_rating_count)
```